# Disable Ethernet Hardware Devices at start-up

Tags: systemd, udev, devices, pci, qubes

To startup vm called "sys-net" in Qubes on my laptop need to write "1" in file

```
echo -n "1" > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:04\:00.0/remove
```

also 0000:04:00.0 and 0000:04:00.1 are conflicts and need to be removed first after every startup laptop.

then network start and work fine. there is some input for information

```
$ lspci | grep -i eth
04:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev12)

$ find /sys -name *04:00.0
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:04:00.0
/sys/bus/pci/drivers/rtsx_pci/0000:04:00.0
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.3/0000:04:00.0

$ find /sys -name *04:00.1
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:04:00.1
/sys/bus/pci/drivers/pciback/0000:04:00.1
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:001d.3/0000:04:00.1
```

How can I convert it to systemd script to run it at start-up? It works only temporarily. After reboot the network device is there again.

Comment: 0000:04:00.0 - its a mmc0 ultra high speed SDR104 SDHC card

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a `udev` rule.

For example, you can create a file `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-disable-eth.rules` with the following content:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", SUBSYSTEMS=="pci", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo 1 >/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:04\:00.0/remove'"
```

Feel free to customize it further to add more specific items, like the vendor attribute, the name of the interface, etc.

Take a look at http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html for more examples and additional information on writing udev rules.