# Can a network interface be activated if the ifcfg-files are missing?

Tags: networking, ifconfig

I have a RHEL/CentOS7 installation with some unused network ports. NetworkManager is not in use on this system, only the legacy "ifupdown" network scripts.

I would like to "disable" the unused network ports to prevent accidental use, and I have considered simply deleting the corresponding `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-*` files. I know that the interface can then no longer be activated manually via `ifup`, but I want to be sure that there is no "default" behavior which would allow a (non-root) user to plug in a network cable and then get these interfaces working anyway.

**So the question is:** Can a network interface be activated by a non-root user (e.g. due to some automatic fall-back behavior) under legacy network scripts if there is no `ifcfg-` file corresponding to that interface? (Alternative formulation: What is the default behavior of a network interface if there is not `ifcfg-` file for it?)

Comment: This? https://serverfault.com/questions/184489/how-to-disable-a-nic-in-centos

Comment: I expect you can set up udev rules that will completely disable the device. Perhaps something [along these lines](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/353851/disable-ethernet-hardware-devices-at-start-up).

Comment: @K-attila- that sounds like a good idea. You may want to turn it into an answer.